# how would I optimizing setting item in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to optimize that

```
_df['side_diff'][_df['s'] == 0] = 0
```

I have profiled the code, and this line takes a lot of time.

```
def diff_last_first(ser):
    try:
        return ser.iloc[-1] - ser.iloc[0]
    except AttributeError:
        return ser[-1] - ser[0]
_df['is_primary'] = _df.groupby(gb)['side'].transform(diff_last_first)
```

Comment: Please clarify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below:

```
_df['side_diff']=np.where((_df['s'] == 0),0,_df['side_diff'])
```

Comment: works like charm, how about this line too ?
    _df['is_primary'] = _df.groupby(gb)['side'].transform(diff_last_first)

Comment: I edited my question for another line of code that needs to be optimized please

Comment: @WaleedSaleh for code optimisation , the ideal platform is [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) i tried what i understood seeing your code before you updated it. Thanks